# Entity Framework doesn't generate ApplicationUser foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Note: for this question, I've simplified the models a bit.

Im working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application (with Entity Framework Core). I have three models. I have an ApplicationUser (that extends from IdentityUser), I have an Activity model and I have a 'SignUp' model that has a foreign key to an activity and a foreign key to ApplicationUser. At least, that's the idea. The thing is, Entity Framework recognices the Activity FK as a FK, but not the applicationuser. That just becomes another int in the database without any FK constraints.

I've tried a lot of things that I found on the internet, but I can't get it to work. This is what I currently have (shortened for clarity):

Activity:

```
public class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
        SignUps = new HashSet<SignUp>();
    }

    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Naam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SignUp> SignUps { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {

        Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Achternaam")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

SignUp:

```
public class SignUp
{
    public int SignUpID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I first did not have the [ForeignKey] attribute (like with activity), but it's there because I was trying to get it working.

As I said above, the Activity FK in SignUp works fine, the Applicationuser FK doesn't. Entity Framework just generates an int in the database without any FK constraints and when scaffolding CRUD pages, it's also not recognized as an FK.

I'm quite new to ASP.net MVC and EF and I have the feeling I'm overlooking something very simple. Facepalm moment incoming?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Activity` relationship works because you have navigation properties involved there. `Activity` has an `ICollection<SignUp>`, so EF is binding to `ActivityID` on `SignUp` to maintain that collection. There is nothing similar being done with `ApplicationUser`. You just have an property called `ApplicationUserID`; EF will not do anything with that because it has no idea it *should*.

Just add a navigation property and you'll be good:

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

Actually, after looking at your code a bit more, I think you may have just messed up with the `ICollection<Activity>` on `ApplicationUser`. There's no direct relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `Activity`. That relationship comes via `SignUp`, which is basically an M2M with a payload. As a result, you should have the following instead:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {

        Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Achternaam")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SignUp> SignUps { get; set; }
}
```

Then, it would function exactly the same as your `Activity` relationship does currently.

Comment: Oh god, that's the facepalm moment I was already expecting... I've overlooked the Acitivity instead of SignUp for probably hours. Ah well, sometimes you start to miss things if you're looking at it too long. Thanks mate! I appreciate your help :)